# Reorder pandas dataframe columns that has columns.name

Tags: pandas

I want to reorder columns of a dataframe generated from `crosstab`. However, the method I used doesn't work because it has columns.name

example data

```
d = {'levels':['High', 'High', 'Mid', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'Mid'], 'converted':[True, True, True, False, False, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

df

```
    levels  converted
0   High    True
1   High    True
2   Mid     True
3   Low     False
4   Low     False
5   Low     True
6   Mid     False
```

than I used `crosstab` to count it
`cb = pd.crosstab(df['levels'], df['converted'])`

cb

```
converted   False   True
levels      
High        0       2
Low         2       1
Mid         1       1
```

I want to swap the order of the two columns. I tried `cb[[True, False]]` and got error `ValueError: Item wrong length 2 instead of 3.`
I guess it's because it has `columns.name`, which is `converted`

Comment: For this particular case you can use `cb[False]=cb.pop(False)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `sort_index`, when the column type is bool, which will make the normal index slice not work

```
cb.sort_index(axis=1,ascending=False)
Out[190]: 
converted  True   False
levels                 
High           2      0
Low            1      2
Mid            1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the dataframe reindex method as below:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'levels':['High', 'High', 'Mid', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'Mid'], 'converted':[True, True, True, False, False, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
cb = pd.crosstab(df['levels'],df['converted'])
print(cb)
column_titles = [True,False]
cb=cb.reindex(columns=column_titles)
print(cb)
```